# Arabic Not Printing Epson TM-T20II

Tags: javascript, printing, epson, epos

I am creating a slip to print Using Epson TM-T20II using javascript.
here is code

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var address = 'http://192.168.192.168/cgi-bin/epos/service.cgi?devid=local_printer&timeout=60000';
    
    var builder = new epson.ePOSBuilder();
    builder.force = true;
    builder.addTextLang('en');
    builder.addTextFont(builder.FONT_A);
    builder.addTextSmooth(true);
    builder.addPageBegin();
    builder.addText('مرحبا بالعالم \n');
    builder.addPageEnd();
    
    var epos = new epson.ePOSPrint(address);
    epos.onreceive = function (res) { alert(res.success); };
    epos.onerror = function (err) { alert(err.status); };
    epos.oncoveropen = function () { alert('coveropen'); };
    epos.send(builder.toString());
```

Everything is working fine except Arabic text.
Arabic text is spliting and printing left to right instead of right to left.
I have tried everything but not able to find any solution in javascript.

[image: Output Image showing arabic print]

Answer (score 0):

you should use UTF8 encoding and decoding

```
 function encode_utf8(s) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}

function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}
```

Comment: where I should decode, can you please explain a bit more according to my code. 
I have tried this by sending encoded string but how printer will decode ??

Comment: Any one answer please?